# Proving that integration is continuous 

Tags: calculus

Define $C([a,b], \mathbb R)$ to be the space of continuous functions $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ with the norm $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$. Let $H : C([a, b], \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the map such that $H(f)$ is the definite integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ for any $f \in C([a,b], \mathbb R)$.

> How do I prove that $H$ is continuous?

*Note [SN]: Edited the question to make it more complete.*

Comment: Continuous in $a$? in $b$? in $f$? If you mean continuous in $f$, you need a topology on the function space first.

Comment: I guess the $C([a,b], \mathbb R)$ space is endowed with the sup-norm. If so, it might be a good idea to mention that in the question. (Also, I think the usual notation is $C([a,b], \mathbb R)$, not $\mathbb C([a,b], \mathbb R)$.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is because it is [Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity):

$$ |H(f)-H(g)|=\left|\int_a^b(f-g)\; dx\right|\leqslant |b-a| \cdot \|f-g\|_{\infty} .$$

Comment: Very grateful actually, I couldn't figure out how to center things, thanks!